# how to implement location based QR code check

Tags: angular, geolocation, geofencing

I am working on an angular app, I am generating QR code using npm package, my requirement is I want to implement location-based QR code. means suppose I have a QR for a hotel if a user is at the hotel location & scan the QR code app should continue to work further like place order n so on . if a user has captured image using the phone of the QR code & scan from a different location the app should not work (user should not place an order).

I thought to work Latitude & Longitude but it is not suitable because it changes at each place at the same location.

How could I implement this? please guide.
any suggestion will be very helpful

Comment: I don’t see why using lat/long would not work? Of course you would not compare them to the fiftieth digit after the decimal point, but you would work with some sort of tolerance interval.

Answer (score 0):

Lat/Long should work if you work on last digits.
[What is the advantage of GeoFence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62694755/what-is-the-advantage-of-geofence)
Here I am trying to understand the use of it.

If not, I would use GeoFencing. Every store has GLN number. I would setup GeoFencing using GLN location.

Cheers